# How to send a notification based on a date in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make for my backend to send a notification each day that that comes closer to an indicated date.

For example, if my user adds the date "13-07-2020", he should be getting a notification "your deadline is in **1** day!" (as today is 12).

I've read in the documentation of Laravel the section about "Task Scheduling", but I'm not sure how to implement it this way, each user will be getting its own notifications.

How is it possible to accomplish this? The documentation states: "Laravel's command scheduler allows you to fluently and expressively define your command schedule within Laravel itself." So, it makes me believe that it is just for commands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would approach this with Laravel commands.

**Creating a command**

To create a command you can run:

```
php artisan make:command NotifyUsers
```

This creates the `NotifyUsers` command.
In the `handle()` function of the command, you can send a message to each user that has a deadline date set.

```php
public function handle() {
  $users = User::whereNotNull('deadline_date')->get();
  foreach($users as $user) {
    $diffInDays = $user->deadline_date->diff(Carbon::now())->days;

    $user->notify("Your deadline is in $diffInDays day!");
  }
}
```

I set the signature of the command to the following:

```php
protected $signature = 'users:notify';
```

This means you can call the command by runnning

```
php artisan users:notify
```

**Scheduling the command**

In the `Console/Kernel.php` class you can schedule the command.
First you should add it to the `$commands` array:

```php
protected $commands = [
  NotifyUsers::class,
];
```

And in the `schedule()` function you can schedule the command to run once every day.

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
  // Here you can execute the command once every day
  $schedule->command('users:notify')->dailyAt('14:00');
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but (sorry, it was my mistake for not pointing out) I got a relationship between users and assignments, I want for the user to get notified on their assignments based on the deadline of the assignment. The approach is literally the same, right?

Comment: @DanielLogvin Yes, the approach would be exactly the same. You would only need to get the assignments of each user in the commands `handle()` function.

Comment: Great, I'll try it out and ask you if something happens during the process. Will reward if it works!

Comment: @DirkHoekstra what if my application having 1 milllion users? will they able to send notification in one go... i think its not

Comment: @Kunal If you have a lot of users I would push the emails on a queue. Then you can have multiple queue workers process the queue in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

"Task Scheduling" - it means that some action is done by cron.

I don't know what you mean by "notification". You mean in app or by email?

1. notification in App - you create a scheduled action, where you insert data into notification table. Table can looks like this: id, user_id, task_id, day
2. email - you send emails to users in that scheduled action.

Comment: I mean, in the app. I'll use the notification to send it through the API later on :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the question is non-technical, my answer will also contain no code.

Create a scheduler command that runs **"quite frequently"** (like every 5 minutes or so). The purpose of this command is to constantly iterate through all of the resources with the date specified by your users and **pick those that match a rule** similar to:

*Date of the record in the future* minus *deadline* = `now()`

In other words you constantly loop through all records that are prior to deadline, and pick those that match a deadline date. Once picked, remember to mark them as "done" after you perform your business logic, so that scheduled command won't pick them again. This can be achieved by an extra boolean flag.